# Commenting regular expressions

Tags: documentation, coding-style, comments

Are there any common practises for commenting the regular expressions: inline comments referring different part of RegEx or general comment for all expression?

Comment: There are but you need to be more specific. For example Bash supports inline comments and Python offers verbose regular expressions.

Comment: My rule of thumb for regular expressions is: if you need to comment the regular expression, it's too complicated.

Comment: And always include this link: http://regexcrossword.com/

Comment: I don't necessarily agree that if you have to comment it, it's too complicated. A complicated regex can still save you tons of eye-glazing imperative code. Use a good descriptive variable name to assign the regex to. If it still isn't clear enough, use a brief comment to convey the original **intent** behind the regular expression.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my view, a good practice is to concisely state in comments what the general idea of the regular expression is.  This saves other developers (or sometimes yourself) the hassle of copy-pasting the regex in a parser like [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), only to understand what it does.

Comment: RegExr will happen anyway, unless the dev is a regex savant.   But I agree with providing a general description; that's what I do with my regexes.

Comment: +1: Anything more detailed will end up being a crash course in regex as a comment.

Comment: This answer and the @zzzzBov comments make sense.

Comment: Not only does it save the hassle of tedious examination of the regular expression to understand it, but it makes the intent of the original programmer clear, especially given the distinct possibility that the original programmer got the regular expression itself wrong the firs time 'round. Having said that, in a lot of cases assigning the regex to a good variable name can count a long way toward providing adequate documentation of intent.

Answer (score 13):

This is somewhat a language specific answer, but no language is stated in the question.

The book ["Dive Into Python"](https://diveintopython3.problemsolving.io/) suggests implementing comments using *Verbose Regular Expressions*:

> Python allows you to do this with something called verbose regular
>   expressions. A verbose regular expression is different from a compact
>   regular expression in two ways:
>
> - Whitespace is ignored. Spaces, tabs, and carriage returns are not
>     matched as spaces, tabs, and carriage returns. They're not matched at
>     all. (If you want to match a space in a verbose regular expression,
>     you'll need to escape it by putting a backslash in front of it.)
> - Comments are ignored. A comment in a verbose regular expression is
>     just like a comment in Python code: it starts with a `#` character and
>     goes until the end of the line. In this case it's a comment within a
>     multi-line string instead of within your source code, but it works the
>     same way.

Example:

```
>>> pattern = """
^                   # beginning of string
M{0,4}              # thousands - 0 to 4 M's
(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})    # hundreds - 900 (CM), 400 (CD), 0-300 (0 to 3 C's),
                    #            or 500-800 (D, followed by 0 to 3 C's)
(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})    # tens - 90 (XC), 40 (XL), 0-30 (0 to 3 X's),
                    #        or 50-80 (L, followed by 0 to 3 X's)
(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})    # ones - 9 (IX), 4 (IV), 0-3 (0 to 3 I's),
                    #        or 5-8 (V, followed by 0 to 3 I's)
$                   # end of string
"""
>>> re.search(pattern, 'M', re.VERBOSE)                1
```

Source and further details [here](https://diveintopython3.problemsolving.io/regular-expressions.html#verbosere)

This method has a slight disadvantage that the caller must know that the pattern is written in a verbose format and call it accordingly.

Comment: Rather than storing the pattern in a variable, you can use `re.compile` at the point where you define your pattern, and only store the resulting object.  That way, the pattern compilation flags (including `re.VERBOSE`) don't need to be separated from the pattern itself.

Comment: Really helpful answer, thanks! But how can I match a `#` if I'm using the verbose flag? By the way: the source links seems to be down.

Comment: Okay, so `#` can be matched literally when inside a character class: `[#]` (source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X)

Comment: @JohnBartholomew In some cases you may not want to call `re.compile()` at the place you define the regex. To include the `VERBOSE` flag into the regex string you can put it in the inline form to the beginning of the regex: `(?x)`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X

Answer (score 9):

Typically, I will write a regex and not explain the individual pieces of the regex, but rather what it's purpose is. That is that what and why. This is a bit like asking "What should my comments look like?" to which one would say "**Don't write what the code is doing, write why the code is doing what it does**"

```
// Strip the leading "?" and remove the query parameters "offset=<integer>" & "count=<integer> so we have a pattern of the request"          
var search = location.search.substring(1).replace(/offset=[0-9]+?&/g, "").replace(/count=[0-9]+?&/g, "");
```

Unless you are trying to teach someone about regexes via comments in code, I don't think explaining what each individual piece will do. When working with other programmers, you can safely assume that one would know something as global regular expressions.

Comment: you would be surprised...

Answer (score 6):

I guess it really depends on how you're putting the regex together.  Generally speaking I think it would be a bad idea to put comments within the actual regex string itself (not possible in most scenarios, as far as I know).  If you really need to comment specific portions of a regular expression (are you trying to teach someone?), then break each chunk into separate strings on their own lines, and comment each line using the normal commenting process for your programming language.  Otherwise, pleinolijf's answer is pretty good.

example:

```
string myregex = "\s" // Match any whitespace once
+ "\n"  // Match one newline character
+ "[a-zA-Z]";  // Match any letter
```

Answer (score 4):

I usually define a string constant whose name describes the overall purpose of the regular expression.

For example:

```
const string FloatingPointNumberPattern = @"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+";
```

You could add a comment above this constant to give it a description, but usually the constant name itself should be enough.

Comment: One extra thing I like about this answer is that if it gets used in more than one spot, the intent *has* to be carried around too - no forgetting to comment it.

Answer (score 3):

In some scenarios, the developer(s) may be using regular expressions to match text outside of their typical domain. The original developers may have gone through a lot of iterations capturing various edge cases that might only have been discovered through that iterative process. Thus, subsequent developers may not be aware of a lot of the edge cases that the original developer(s) dealt with, even if they are aware of the general case.

In cases such as these, it may be worthwhile to document examples of the variations. The location of this documentation may vary depending on amount (e.g., not necessarily in the code).

One way to approach it is to assume that future developers will only have basic knowledge, like how regular expressions work, but not any knowledge that you either (1) had prior to development of the regular expressions that wouldn't necessarily be known to the future developers or (2) knowledge that you gained during development (e.g., edge cases that were discovered).

For example, if during development you say something like "Oh, I didn't know that X could take this form," then it's worth documenting that (and maybe the part of the regex that handles that variation).

Answer (score 2):

Comments should add useful information that is not obvious from the code.

1. Make it easy to understand what the expression is supposed to do at a requirements level, either in the code itself or in a comment. What is the intent behind the expression, is it to validate email addresses or pick out Canadian phone numbers.
2. Make it easy to understand what the expression is actually doing, i.e. what the expression evaluates to. First try to make it clear by splitting up the expression, if you first check for all hyphens then remove all numbers then make that a two part expression with variables holding the intermediary values, it will make it much easier to read and the reader will be able to step through your logic one step at a time. (There is a famous answer to a question on SE where someone is trying to decipher some old code which involves bit manipulation '>>' and finding out if certain flags are set where the answer lays out not only what the code really does but how the question's authour should go about deconstructing this kind of code in the future which is exactly what I am trying to describe but I can't seem to find the question to link to)

There are few applications that need every last cycle, if you are pattern matching massive data sets then maybe there is a better way, maybe not, but for most things the extra execution time is not that big a deal.

And remember the next person to come across your code and fix a bug might be you in six months time and there is no way you are going to remember what it was supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the RegEx into a separate class into a with a meaningful name. Then I'd document the code with automated tests.

This will ensure

- That the code actually works - also for corner cases
- Ensures that a quick "bugfix" doesn't screw up a lot of corner cases
- May document optimizations where backtracking is disabled

Naturally, your class may host several regex's.